# How to monitor docker containers log from non-root user?

Tags: docker, fluentd

I want to monitor docker containers log from non-root user(td-agent) and on host server,

```
sudo chmod o+rx /var/lib/docker
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} \;
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -exec chmod o+r {} \;
```

But containers directory rollback 600 and each container directory keep 600.

```
# find /var/lib/docker/containers -ls
143142    4 drwx------   4 root     root         4096 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers
146027    4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d
146031    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          190 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d/hostconfig.json
146046    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           13 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d/hostname
146047    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          174 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d/hosts
146030    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         3305 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d/config.json
146049    4 -rw-------   1 root     root         1853 Aug 14 12:00 /var/lib/docker/containers/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d/145efa73652aad14e1706e8fcd1597ccbbb49fd756047f3931270b46fe01945d-json.log
146050    4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370
146054    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          190 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370/hostconfig.json
146056    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           13 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370/hostname
146057    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          174 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370/hosts
146053    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         3286 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370/config.json
146058    4 -rw-------   1 root     root         1843 Aug 14 12:01 /var/lib/docker/containers/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370/f09796f978ef5bab1449d2d10d400228eb76376579e7e33c615313eeed53f370-json.log
```

How to monitor this each `json.log`? or any other good monitoring way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[logspout](https://github.com/progrium/logspout/) is another way to collect containers`logs. I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it is very interesting and consistent way to collect containers` logs.

You just need to run `logspout` container. This container has a feature that send docker containers' logs to other syslog server. (or you can use HTTP api also. see [repository](https://github.com/progrium/logspout/))

```
# (172.17.42.1 is host ip address)
$ docker run -v=/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock progrium/logspout syslog://172.17.42.1:5140
```

And fluentd that is running on host can handle these logs through syslog protocal. Below is td-agent.conf example. It receive logs from syslog protocal and send them to elasticsearch server. (check this [example project](https://github.com/nacyot/docker-logs/tree/master/agent-td/syslog_to_elasticsearch))

```
<source>
  type syslog
  port 5140
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag syslog.udp
  format /^(?<time>.*?) (?<container_id>.*?) (?<container_name>.*?): (?<message>.*?)$/
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
</source>

<match syslog.**>
  index_name <ES_INDEX_NAME>
  type_name <ES_TYPE_NAME>
  type elasticsearch
  host <ES_HOST>
  port <ES_PORT>
  flush_interval 3s
</match>
```

Comment: I choose this solution!

Comment: This approch is somewhat risky because Docker have a memory leak problem related with log(https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9139). This problem will be fixed when Docker 1.5.1 released(https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10347).

Answer (score 1):

As I discussed in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807557/how-to-ship-logs-in-a-microservice-architecture-with-docker/24808726#24808726) that the OP never acknowledged whatsoever, I find the best approach is to configure the applications running within the container to log messages to syslog, and mount the host's syslog socket to the container.

`docker run -v /dev/log:/dev/log ...`

Downside of this approach is that if the syslog daemon on the host is restarted, the container will lose it's socket since the daemon recreates the socket at restart.

A fix for this would be to add another socket (in rsyslog this can be done using the [`imuxsock` module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html#configuration-parameters)). Create the additional socket in some known directory, then bind mount the directory instead of `/dev/log` directly. The additional socket will also be removed when rsyslog restarts, but will be recreated and available to the application in the directory following the restart.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to deal with this issue is to mount host's `/sys/fs/cgroup` into a Docker container that's running in_docker_metrics. See https://github.com/bdehamer/docker-librato

Answer (score 0):

Sematext Docker Agent (open-source, github) can do this for you.  You won't need td-agent.  SDA will collect logs, but also events and metrics.  See https://github.com/sematext/sematext-agent-docker and 
https://sematext.com/docker